# incrementing variables in awk if-else

Tags: awk

I have the following code:

```
TOTAL=0
COUNT=0

# a ratio of 10000 indicates that ILP # rejected was 0.
awk -v c=$COUNT -v t=$TOTAL 
'BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1       { $(NF+1)="RATIO" }
NR>1 && NF>3{ if($4==0) $(NF+1)=10000; else {$(NF+1)=$6/$4, c++, t=t+$4} } 
{ print }' "$FILE" > temp.log

AVG=$(($TOTAL/$COUNT))
```

TLDR; I have a file with fields and I am adding a new field to every row. In the `else` case, I want to increment my external variables `c` and `t`.

The error I am getting is a `syntax error` pointing at the comma immediately preceding `c++`.

I've read some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683132/counter-in-in-awk-if-else-loop) which do use this comma syntax, so I'm wondering how I can fix this.

Comment: AFAIK, the comma is used to separate *arguments* - to separate *statements* you need a semicolon `;` (or a newline). See for example [(semicolon), separating statements in actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_003b-_0028semicolon_0029)

Comment: @steeldriver You should make this an answer instead of a comment, since it is the answer.

Comment: @camh thanks but I don't think it really answers the question, since the shell variables are passed by value - so even after correcting the awk syntax the OP's approach is not going to work

Comment: @steeldriver You're right - I didn't pay much attention to the stuff around it - trying to change an environment variable from a child process will never work. But at least the syntax error will go away :)

Comment: Don't use all upper case for non-exported shell variable names, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization. Do always quote shell strings, including when setting the awk vars from them, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Aside of the problem that [pointed out](/users/65304/) in the comment:

> the comma is used to separate arguments - to separate statements you
> need a semicolon ; (or a newline). See for example  [(semicolon), separating statements in actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_003b-_0028semicolon_0029)

you don't need to initialize the *TOTAL* and *COUNT* variables within shell, nor you cannot easily update their value within *awk*; instead, let *awk* calculate the AVG for you, try:

```
awk 'BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1       { $(NF+1)="ratio" }
NR>1 && NF>3{ if($4==0) $(NF+1) =10000; else { $(NF+1) =$6/$4; count++; total+=$4 } }
{ print }
END{ if(count) print "AVG: " total/count }' infile
```